# How can I add attribute inside an input tag using jQuery?

Tags: javascript

HTML is:

```
<div class="form-item" id="edit-image-upload-wrapper"><img id="img_prev" src="#">
     <label for="edit-image-upload">Upload Your Picture: <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label>
     <input type="file" name="files[image_upload]" class="form-file required" id="edit-image-upload" size="60"></input>

     <div class="description"><p>You need to provide a passport sized image in jpg/jpeg or png format. The image size has to be 100kb or lower.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
```

JS code:

```
$('#edit-image-upload-wrapper input').prepend('onchange="readURL(this);"');
```

due to this JS code input tag has been changed as follows:

```
<input type="file" name="files[image_upload]" class="form-file required" id="edit-image-upload" size="60">onchange="readURL(this);"</input>
```

I want to change as follows:

```
 <input type="file" name="files[image_upload]" class="form-file required" id="edit-image-upload" size="60" onchange="readURL(this);"></input>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Did you tried to use .attr() instead of .prepend()?

Comment: first thing `<input>` is a singular tag, means it has no end tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, to add (or update) an attribute to an element, you can use [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr):

```
$('#edit-image-upload-wrapper input').attr('onchange', 'readURL(this);');
```

As that attribute is reflected as a property, [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop) would also work:

```
$('#edit-image-upload-wrapper input').prop('onchange', 'readURL(this);');
```

**However**, as you're using jQuery, I can't see any good reason for doing this as opposed to using proper [event hookup](http://api.jquery.com/on), such as:

```
$('#edit-image-upload-wrapper input').on('change', function() {
    readURL(this);
});
```

And if you can change the `readURL` function so that it gets the URL from `this` rather than from its first argument, that can be simpler:

```
// Requires small change to `readURL`
$('#edit-image-upload-wrapper input').on('change', readURL);
```

---

Side note 1: Your `input` has its own `id` value (`edit-image-upload`), so those selectors could be simply `#edit-image-upload`, rather than `#edit-image-upload-wrapper input`.

---

Side note 2: Your HTML is invalid. `input` elements are ["void" elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#void-elements), they never have content, and so you never write an ending tag for them. E.g., you never write `</input>`. Any element that **cannot** have content (`input`, `br`, `hr`, and a few others) is never written with an end tag.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'on'

Comment: @AbdusSattarBhuiyan: Wow, you're using a **really** outdated copy of jQuery. I strongly recommend updating to something more recent. `on` was added in v1.7.0 nearly three years ago (current versions are v1.11.1 and v2.1.1). Anyway, with older versions it would be `.bind("change", function...` or in either version, just `.change(function...`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$('#edit-image-upload-wrapper input').change(function() {
     //.....
});
```